# i can't configure esp-idf version 4.4.6

Tags: esp-idf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g476k.png) I am writing to seek assistance with a persistent issue I'm encountering while trying to configure ESP-IDF v4.4.6 in Visual Studio Code (VSCode).

The problem I'm facing is during the configuration process. Everything seems to be going smoothly until the progress reaches 99.93%, at which point it becomes stuck. I have tried to troubleshoot the issue using various methods, including checking my internet connection, ensuring system requirements are met, and even performing a clean installation. However, I've been unable to resolve this problem.

I am using VSCode as my development environment, and I've followed the official ESP-IDF installation instructions meticulously. My computer has ample resources, and my internet connection is stable. I've also checked for any error messages in the terminal, but none are displayed; it simply halts at 99.93%.

I kindly request your assistance in resolving this issue so that I can proceed with my development endeavors using ESP-IDF. If you require any additional information or logs to diagnose the problem, please let me know, and I will provide them promptly. Your guidance and support would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and consideration.